# Instagram API won't work online

Tags: php, json, instagram-api

I've been trying to get photo feeds on a website from Instagram. The photos show up on my localhost but when I upload the coding on an online server, they don't show up and I get this error:

> **Warning:** Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in H:\root\home\mywebsite\www\site1\index.php on line 290

Here is my code:

```
//Instagram
$userid = "103#####10";
$accessToken = "1036#####.ab#####.7b53a###a3b74f9#############d438";
$url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{$userid}/media/recent/?access_token={$accessToken}";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 
$result = json_decode($result);

<?php foreach ($result->data as $post): ?>
    <a class="fancybox" href="<?php echo $post->images->standard_resolution->url ?>" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="<?php echo $post->caption->text ?>"><img src="<?php echo $post->images->thumbnail->url ?>" alt="<?php echo $post->caption->text ?>" /></a>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

I've been trying to find a solution to this online for a while now. Please advise me in what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

If it works on your local and not in your server, is because the URL and the callback URL have change (from your localhost to your server).

You need to change your configuration in the Instagram settings page.

Check out the info [here](https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/).

**EDIT**

Set you your configuration up [here](https://instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/). You will see the following menu. There, change the WebsiteURL and the Redirect URI to your server ones.

[image: Manage accounts]

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more? I had set up my configuration but I thought I didn't need it since you only need a userID and Access token and not the Client ID and Client secret  to get a user's images, correct?

Comment: Yes, the website URL and Redirect URI are of the server ones.

Comment: could you please copy&paste the url you use with curl in a browser and tell me the error?

Comment: https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{$userid}/media/recent/?access_token={$accessToken}  Do you mean this?

Comment: the result of pasting it in the browser. edit your post and add it please